# Show a UIDocumentActivityViewController from a UIActivity without using an acitivityViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uiactivityviewcontroller, uidocumentinteraction

I wanted to use the [DMActivityInstagram](https://github.com/coryalder/DMActivityInstagram) inside my app, but there's no need to resize my image so I'd like to skip the "resizer" step (so I don't want to override the `- (UIViewController *)activityViewController`) but want to go to the `performActivity` directly, however, when I try to open the UIDocumentActivityViewController there I get the error:

```
"Attempt to present <_UIDocumentActivityViewController>  on <MyViewController> which is already presenting <UIActivityViewController>"
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Hey @Pieter, did you ever find a way to do this? I would like to do the same thing. Thanks.

Comment: @BillRollins no, since I couldn't get it to work without the additional step, I opted for a UIDocumentInteractionController instead